# SSRS Iif Evaluates True and False

Tags: reporting-services, iif

MSDN states that SSRS will evaluate both the true and false part of an `Iif` statement regardless of which one is returned. This seems to make `Iif` completely useless in regard to error avoidance. In other words, you cannot use `Iif` to skirt around an error, so essentially any operation you choose to include must always be valid regardless of the conditions. Honestly, what good is this?

So my question is... Does SSRS have other ways of evaluating conditions besides `Iif`?

Here is my example.  I just want to be able to return Left without grabbing the first character of the match.

```
=Iif
(
    InStr(Fields!SearchField.Value, Fields!Criteria.Value) <= 1,    
    "",             
    Left(Fields!SearchField.Value, InStr(Fields!SearchField.Value, Fields!Criteria.Value)-1)                    
)
```

However, what is happening here is that `InStr(Fields!Criteria.Value, Fields!Criteria.Value)-1` is evaluating to 0 in some cases, which is perfectly fine until the FALSE part of the statement tries to deduct 1 from it and pass it into the `InStr` function. `InStr` cannot accept -1 as the number of characters to return.

An oversimplification of this is as follows.  Assume you have a situation where Value can never fall below 0 without throwing an error.

```
Iif (Value > 0, Value = Value -1, 0)
```

Trying to use `Iif` to force the value not to fall below 0 does not work because all of these statements get evaluated even if they do not meet the conditions.

Trying to use `InStr` to get an index on a match, and Left to build a substring based on that index fails because of this.  I have no idea how to completely avoid the condition.

Comment: I thought SSRS used short-circuit bool evaluation until recently myself. IIF() is a function and all expressions are evaluated before a comparison is made. You could place your expression in the report code and assign a value like Code.FormatWhenFoundOrEmpty(x,y)

Comment: Is it just me, or is this extremely short-sighted on the part of Microsoft?  I mean, the whole idea of conditional statements is to do something when a condition is met and not do it otherwise.  It is probably important to note that this a really counter-intuitive situation.  I was very surprised to encounter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final result from C Black's suggestion to use custom code.  I had eventually hoped to use the segment of the string to format the match in a different color in the opposite column.  I had to add some html tags.  It works perfectly.  Thank you all for your assistance.

Code block:

```
Public Function ParseMatch (ByVal FullString As String, ByVal Criteria As String) As String

    Dim Segment(2) As String
    Dim Result As String

    If FullString.ToUpper.Contains(Criteria.ToUpper)

        Segment(0) = Left(FullString, InStr(Ucase(FullString), Ucase(Criteria) )-1 )
        Segment(1) = Criteria
        Segment(2) = Right(FullString, Len(FullString) - Len(Segment(0)) - Len(Criteria))

        Result = Segment(0) & "<b><FONT color=blue>" & Segment(1) & "</FONT></b>" & Segment(2)

    Else
        Result = FullString
    End If

    Return Result

End Function
```

Report cell:

```
=Code.ParseMatch(Fields!Defendants.Value, Fields!Firm_Client_Name.Value)
```

If the name is found in the list of defendants, it colors the text blue in that field and bolds it.

Answer (score 0):

I too thought `Switch` would work, but upon testing it did not. As far as I can tell, custom code is the only way to go. I tested the function below which worked for my few test cases.

```
Public Function TruncateWord(ByVal str As String, ByVal criteria As String) As String
If str.Contains(criteria) Then
    Return Left(str, InStr(str, criteria) - 1)
Else:
    Return ""
End If
End Function
```

I tested with the below 5 basic strings, searching for "d", and got the following results:

```
+-----------------+
| String | Result |
+-----------------+
| asdf   | as     |
| asd    | as     |
| as     |        |
| da     |        |
| ad     | a      |
+-----------------+
```

So this appears to work for all 3 possible cases (`InStr` returns > 1, `InStr` returns 1, and `InStr` returns 0) from my limited testing.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I think this will work.  I was hoping to avoid custom code, but if this is the only way, I will definitely have to go this route.

Answer (score -1):

Use `SWITCH`

`SWITCH` stops evaluating expression as soon as the first True is found. Switch works with pairs (an expression to evaluate and a result if it's true). The final `True` acts like an `else`.

```
=SWITCH
(
InStr(Fields!SearchField.Value, Fields!Criteria.Value) <= 1, "",
True, Left(Fields!SearchField.Value, InStr(Fields!Criteria.Value, Fields!Criteria.Value)-1)                   
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Alan!  I will try that and see if I can rework the issue.

Comment: Actually, this produces the exact same results.  I made an edit above because I had the sample fields wrong.  They are correct in the real code, though.  Same situation, though.  It won't create the "" value and stop there.

Comment: I even explicitly defined the condition as InStr(Fields!SearchField.Value, Fields!Criteria.Value) > 1

No joy.

Comment: I'll take a look later if I get chance. Can you give 2 or 3 sample values for each field

Comment: See below.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I rewrote it for readability:

```
=Switch
(
    InStr(Fields!Defendants.Value, Fields!Firm_Client_Name.Value) = 0, "",  
    InStr(Fields!Defendants.Value, Fields!Firm_Client_Name.Value) = 1, "",  
    True, Left(Fields!Defendants.Value, InStr(Fields!Defendants.Value, Fields!Firm_Client_Name.Value)-1)
)
```

' 0 = Error

' 1 =

' >1 = substring based on criteria

1 and >1 are correct, but I still get the error when the InStr evaluates to 0.

The thing is, I have to tell the Left function -1 or it will return the first letter of the delimiter, which I do not want.  Even though the condition of InStr(Fields!Defendants.Value, Fields!Firm_Client_Name.Value) = 0 is true, instead of returning "" for the column,  it returns an error.  This tells me it is still being evaluated despite it being outside of the specified condition.

If I omit the -1 within the Left function, no error results.  Yet I get substring + first letter of delimiter.

I work with sensitive information, so I cannot give specific results of the strings.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for each field, even if you make it up and expected results in each case.